# How to structure related RESTful URLs

Tags: api, rest, restful-architecture, restful-url

I have two resource, `buildings` and `rooms`.

The logical API URL would be:

```
/api/buildings            ->   all buildings
/api/buildings/1          ->   building #1
/api/buildings/1/rooms    ->   rooms from building #1
/api/buildings/1/rooms/5  ->   room #5 from building #1
/api/rooms                ->   all rooms, any building
/api/rooms/5              ->   room #5 / (?) Is this necessary?
```

How do you structure deeper nodes? It seems like there are 3 ways to get the same data when we introduce a 3rd layer

```
#1) /api/buildings/1/rooms/5/chairs/3  

#2) /api/rooms/5/chairs/3

#3) /api/chairs/3
```

Seems like there are different ways to get chair #3, which would mean duplicate work.

Comment: Does every chair have a unique ID - regardless of which building it is in?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make sense to have `/api/buildings/1/rooms/5/chairs/3` or `/api/rooms/5/chairs/3`. The `api/.../chairs` resources should have a link to `/api/chairs/3` and the `/api/buildings/1/rooms` resource should include a link to `/api/rooms/5/`.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean when you say `should have a link to`?

Comment: The response from `GET /api/rooms/` should include a hypertext link to `/api/rooms/5/`, e.g., `['api/rooms/5/', ...]` for JSON or `<rooms><room href='api/rooms/5/' /></rooms>` in XML.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying to avoid nesting where possible.

```
/api/buildings
/api/buildings/1
/api/buildings/1/rooms
  # GET returns all rooms in building 1. Each room has a "self" link
  # which points to /rooms/{id}, and a "building" link which points to 
  # /api/buildings/1
  # POST adds a room to the building and the rooms collection
  # DELETE deletes the room from the building and the rooms collection
  # This is reasonable because a room's scope is the building it belongs to

/api/rooms
  # No POST supported
  # DELETE deletes the room from its building and this collection
/api/rooms/5 
/api/rooms/5/chairs
  # All chairs currently in this room
  # POST moves an existing chair to this room
  # DELETE removes an existing chair from the room, but not /chairs

/api/chairs
  # POST creates a chair
  # DELETE deletes the chair and removes it from the room it belongs to
```

A possible problem is that POST acts differently in `/buildings/1/rooms` and `/rooms/5/chairs`. It's up to you as to whether this inconsistency is acceptable or not. Alternatives are:

- allow/force the user to create a room via POST /rooms and then as a separate transaction assign it to the building via POST /buildings/5/rooms
- make the building a room belongs to a required part of its construction when POSTing to /rooms
- use a query parameter, such as `POST /rooms?building=12 { body }`. This construction is atypical and not recommended.